I increased my NDF files from 3 files to 7 files. How to re-distribute the data across MDF and NDF files?
I have a big database that uses 1 MDF files and 4 NDF files. The MDF file is placed in a 2TB disk and NDF files are placed in 500GB disks separately. I set the MDF file to be unlimited, while the NDF files have a max size of 450GB.
Currently all my NDF files have reached 450GB so they can't store any new data, making all new data will go to the MDF file instead. Unfortunately, the disk used by MDF file is also running out of space. I have an idea to increase the storage while simultaneously distributing the data to more disks, so I asked my server admin to create 3 new disks, which I created 3 new NDF files to each disk. So now I have 1 MDF file and 7 NDF files.
The problem is, even though I have 7 NDF files, 4 of them are already full so I can't fully utilize their usage to store new data. The file usage can be seen like this:

And now I have an idea to re-distribute the full NDF files so they can be distributed to new NDF files, so all 7 NDF files can be functional again. I only know the method of distributing space from 1 MDF files to several new NDF files from this Link, but I can't seem to find the way to re-distribute MDF and NDF files if some NDF files are already present.
Can anyone give some hint on how to do that? Any help would be great.

"The problem is, even though I have 7 NDF files, 4 of them are already full so I can't fully utilize their usage to store new data." - Why does it matter to you which NDF the new data goes to?

With disks being so cheap and large, why are you bothering to keep small files?

@J.D. Because I thought if all NDF files are functional the performance would be more effective?

@RohitGupta because my server admin always says that our disk pool is depleting so we need to conserve the disk usage. I have no knowledge of anything about the server.

@AffanWidyan Well from a read perspective it'll make no difference because your data is already split across the NDFs, so to redistribute them further to read a row from a different NDF than what it was previously on is just shifting the same amount of data to be read, to a different location. From a write perspective, only if you're writing more data simultaneously than the max write speed of the disk and of each NDF is on a separate physical disk, would it help writes. But considering the average SSD can write 500 MB of data per second, you'd have to be writing a ton of data at one time.
